# What software should I use to encrypt my hard drive?

Tags: security, disk-encryption

I am currently running Windows 7 RC x64 on my home system, and am interested in encrypting my hard drive.  I've heard good things about TrueCrypt, but am curious what other folks might suggest.  I primarily use my system for software development, so am concerned about any system performance degradation that encryption might introduce.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is the de facto standard.

Free open-source disk encryption software for Windows Vista/XP, Mac OS X, and Linux.

> The following features are planned to
>   be implemented in future versions:
>
> Full support for Windows 7

Comment: I installed TrueCrypt 7.0.  Works great with no issues.  Incidentally, the new version now supports hardware-accelerated AES.  I see no performance issues or system degradation whatsoever.

Comment: Please note [TrueCrypt](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/) development was ended in 04/2014 and isn't secure anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 has full disk encryption built in with Bitlocker. You will have it available in the RC but come RTM it will only be available in the Enterpise and Ultimate editions.

Comment: Is the source code available for BitLocker?  I believe it isn't (it is for TrueCrypt.org though), and from a security perspective this eliminates BitLocker as a possible option because I can't review the source code.  (For encryption and security software, open source is extremely important because anyone can review the code.)

Comment: @RandolfRichardson, Depends on who you are trying to hide from. If you are trying to hide from the US gov, you can be sure that Windows has "some contracts" that allows the FBI to backdoor.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, there's TrueCrypt.

There's also [PGP Whole Disk Encryption](http://www.pgp.com/products/wholediskencryption/).

If you purchase Windows 7 Ultimate, you'll also have BitLocker built in, which is one of the few compelling features of Ultimate.

Comment: I bought the PGP disk encryption software way back in the day.  They discovered a bug in the software and decided to wait until the next major version to patch it.  That version was not available as a free upgrade.

This was quite some time ago, but it left a bad taste in my mouth.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Dekart](http://www.private-disk.net/) private disk. It ships with AES 256-bit encryption and can be used from a memory stick.