# encryption software for portable media, that works on both Mac OSX and Windows

Tags: encryption, portable

I'm looking for software that can encrypt portable media (hard drive or thumb drive) in such a way that it's transparent to the OS, and is portable between Mac OSX and Windows. (trying to regularly transfer files between two computers, and just want to be safe in case I lose a thumb drive in transit)

Any suggestions?

I did see [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/127/recommendations-for-good-disk-encryption) but it doesn't address the issue and I can't tell from the TrueCrypt docs.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/381849/cross-platform-file-encryption-tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) works great between OS X and Windows.  I've got a thumb drive that uses full-disk encryption, and I have had no problem using it to transfer files between multiple Mac and Windows computers.