# What is the best way to encrypt folders in your hard drive?

Tags: encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What software should I use to encrypt my hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/127/what-software-should-i-use-to-encrypt-my-hard-drive)

Hi,

What is the easiest/most secure way of encrypting folders on my external HD or laptop ?

Comment: which OS? OS X has encrypted disk images.

Answer (score 11):

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is an excellent, cross platform, open source implementation for securing your data.

Answer (score 2):

I am avid fan of [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a truecrypt container.

It creates a file that acts as hard disk image, and it's encrypted with truecrypt.

As for your external drive, you could encrypt that all together.

Answer (score 0):

I use this [EncFS](http://www.arg0.net/encfs) tool, it lets you mount a folder of encrypted files into an folder of unencrypted files. The use of EncFS is very straightforward and incomplicated. The only real problem is, that this tool exists only for linux, BSD nd Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X includes Disk Utility, which can be used to create an encrypted image or sparse image.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Windows 7 Ultimate or Enterprise, you can use [BitLocker to go](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/bitlocker.aspx), which "gives the lockdown treatment to easily-misplaced portable storage devices like USB flash drives and external hard drives."